Why is there random stuff in my string when printing its bytes?
I'm trying to see how format string bug works and tried to explore it by myself.
This is a simple program:
#include"stdio.h"
#include"string.h"

struct mystruct{
    char buf[32];
    int num;
};
typedef struct mystruct *mys;

void myfunction2(){
    struct mystruct struct1;
    mys p1 = &struct1;
    p1->num = 43981;
    strcpy(p1->buf,"caaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac"); // there are 31 characters in order to fit the \0
    printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    myfunction2();
    return 0;
}

Output:
61616161 61616163 61616161 ff78bf10 ff7b6040 61616163 61616161 61616161 61616161 abcd fffedfb0 fffee000

What is "ff78bf10 ff7b6040" doing in there? And why isn't "61616163" ("caaa" in hex) at the start and end of the string but is at random places?
I expected to see 61616163 at the start and end of the string.
I also expected a 63616161 to appear since it starts with a c and ends with a c.
I didn't expect to see random stuff in the middle of my string bytes.

What arguments are you passing to printf?

Is your compiler giving you any warnings when you compile this code? Do you care about them? Did you try to fix them? Treat all warnings as errors. gcc with no special parameters gives lots of warnings for this code (for the printf()).

yes it is giving me warnings (expecting printf arguments match) but I ignore them because I'm trying to understand how format string exploitation works

Format string exploitation relying on undefined behaviour gets undefined results.  Ignoring warnings about miscalled functions like printf() means you can't complain when you don't get the result you would like.

printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x"); asks printf to print 12 unsigned int values but does not pass it those values. In a typical situation, in the absence of interference from optimization and other factors, printf will nonetheless retrieve values from where the arguments should have been passed.
Probably, in your C implementation, the first several of those arguments would be passed in CPU registers, and the remaining arguments would be passed on the stack. So printf gets values from those places. They hold data leftover from earlier actions in your program. printf is printing this data, and it is not particularly informative.
